# ¿Cómo validar un máximo de números en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

¿Cómo podria validar en laravel que mi campo "intentos" solo pueda aceptar números del 1 al 3 con `validate` que proporciona este framework?

He probado con `digits_between` pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Probaste `integer|min:1|max:3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la regla debería ser:

```
$request->validate([
                     'intentos' => 'required|integer|between:1,3',
                  ]);
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-between